# How to trim the timestamp (i know, been asked before....)

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, trim

My server response date/timestamp is in XML format, looks like this:

```
<au_updated_date>2018-02-04T13:32:58</au_updated_date>
```

All I want is `2018-02-04`

Tried this but it displays nothing:

```
[date_format("au_updated_date","Y-m-d")]
```

Also tried some trim, string and substring functions to no avail :(

por favor?

EDIT:

Still not working :(

Perhaps this could be useful:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($response,true);
```

Then looping thru the response and displaying in an html table.

```
echo '<td align=left style="text-align:left">', ($data["results"][$i]["card"]["au_updated_date"]), '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg, i got it!

only took about 4 hours of banging on it lol

instead of this:

```
$au_dates = $au_record->getElementsByTagName( "au_updated_date" );
$au_date = $au_dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I did this:

```
$au_dates = $au_record->getElementsByTagName( "au_updated_date" );
$au_date = $au_dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($au_date));
```

Thanks Everyone, especially Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse and format it like this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2018-02-04T13:32:58'))
```

Comment: It looks like the OP needs a regex to extract the actual value to use with `strtotime`

Comment: @Martin why would regex be needed?

Comment: @Andreas well regex would be overkill, but something to remove the `<..>` aspects of the string.

Comment: That `<..>` part is called HTML or XML and is removed by the native php function strip_tags(). @Martin

Comment: @Andreas depending on the reliability of the input data I may not suggest  `strip_tags` because it [does not actually validate the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) so a partial or broken tag can result in the removal of more data than expected.

Comment: @Martin if that is the case "1970" will be returned and can easily be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags to remove the XML.
Then use strtotime to get the Unix time of the string.
Then use date to parse it to suit.

```
$str = "<au_updated_date>2018-02-04T13:32:58</au_updated_date>";

Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(strip_tags($str)));
```